# Как выполнить поиск в БД не нагружая сервер?

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, оптимизация, поиск

Есть таблица в БД (MS SQL) которая, к примеру, содержит 10 млн. записей. Один из столбцов данной таблицы содержит, к примеру, номера телефонов в любом произвольном формате, пример:

```
+7(800)880-80-80
+78008808080
7(800)880-80-80
78008808080
+7(800)880 80 80
7 800 880 80 80
```

и т.д.

Необходимо выполнять поиск по номеру телефона. Мне не известно в каком формате введен номер телефона в БД. К примеру я буду вводить: `78008808080`, а номер сохранен в каком нибудь другом формате, следовательно мне вернется ответ что такой записи не найдено. Как можно реализовать поиск, который будет игнорировать все символы и пробелы кроме цифр и сравнивать только цифры?

Используя оператор Like мне все равно нужно знать как именно сохранен номер что бы искать его хотя бы частично:

```
DECLARE
    @Phone NVARCHAR = NULL
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE @Phone IS NULL OR t1.Phone LIKE @Phone + '%'
```

Единственный вариант, который приходит на ум, это:

1. Сначала получаю все записи из БД.
2. Потом пробегаюсь по всем записям и удаляю лишние символы и т.д. и привожу строку в вид: `78008808080`.
3. Потом пробегаюсь по всем записям опять и нахожу нужные мне совпадения.

Такой вариант мне не подходит, потому что он займет большое время и будет большая нагрузка на сервер. Может кто сможет предложить что либо адекватное, без таких затрат времени и  без большой нагрузки на сервер? Выслушаю любые предложения.

Comment: Канонизировать столбец при сохранении. Так все телефоны будут в одном формате. При желании - добавить отдельную колонку для этого, актуальность поддерживать триггерами.

Comment: @TotalPusher тоже смотрел на такой вариант, и теперь при добавлении новых записей в БД будут добавляться записи в определенном формате. Но что делать с уже существующими записями? Писать скрипт который нормализует все существующие записи - вообще не вариант. Как то без этого обойтись нужно.

Comment: Значит сделайте запросом типа REPLACE все скобки, плюсы, минусы, что-то еще. Перебирать на хост-языке - жесть, эту работа должна делать БД. Второй вариант - прикрутить еще одну БД, предназначенную специально для поиска. Я использую Sphinx

Comment: Еще можно так: канонизировать на ходу. Получится что-то типа `WHERE '78008808080' = REPLACE(Phone, '(', '')`, только вложите REPLACE друг в друга для замены всех символов. И это долго если записей много. И это не может использовать индексы.

Comment: @Sanvirtus писать скрипт не вариант? совсем обленились. скрипт-то выполняется всего лишь раз в косоли админа. И аналогичный помещается в тригер after insert|update. тоже всего лишь раз

Comment: а что за база такая интересная, 10млн и номера телефонов, не поделитесь??))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было принято следующее решение:
Создал дополнительную таблицу в которой теперь в одном поле содержаться номера в произвольном формате, а во втором поле нормализованные номера. Поиск выполняю по полю с нормализованными номерами.

Comment: а зачем хранить не нормализованный номер? Может есть смысл его форматировать на лету? Для 10млн записей это избыточно как по мне

Answer (score 2):

Правильным решением будет все же привести базу к общему формату. Тогда и при выводе легче форматировать, и валидировать легче, и гляди из 10 млн останется парочка так как уберутся дубликаты.

А вообще можно так выбрать нужные записи

```
SELECT
    *
FROM user_contact u
WHERE u.value LIKE '%7%8%0%0%8%8%0%8%0%8%0%'
```

Хотя нужно понимать что попадут куча фальшивых значений к примеру `178008808080` тоже пройдет этот фильтр

Также не мешало бы узнать версию MySQL
Ибо есть такое для 8-й версии))
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

Когда то делала подобным образом для поиска слов в строке БД

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(word, string_list)
```

Но не уверена, как будет работать с числами, потому что может находить возможные подобные комбинации в других номерах, что я, так понимаю, не желательно